# i have included same directive in 2 html file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

Hello I have included the directive in 2 html files. app is ng-app.

```
<dir auto=""></div>
```

code in a directive

```
app.directive("auto", function() {
  scope: {
    arr : "="
  },
  templateUrl : "myHtml.hmtl",
  restrict : 'EAC',
  link : function(element,scope,attrs) {
    scope.getData = function() {
      //here data is store in arr variable
    };
    scope.getData();
  }
});
```

now in myHtml.html file i have used the arr. i have used ng-repeat in myHtml.html file. For ng-repeat i have used arr.

My problem is in one file i am able to get the data in myHtml.html file. but in another html file i have used the same directive but i am not able to get the data.

sorry I am not having a much time  to make  a jsFiddle or plunker for the same.

Comment: How do you want us to help you with so few info?

Answer (score 1):

Are you passing in the `arr` to the directive in both instances? It doesn't look like it from the code you posted, the correct way to use that directive would be:

`<div auto arr="myArr"></div>`

and your parent controllers `$scope`:

`$scope.myArr=[1,2,3,4,5....];`

Also there are multiple typos there, myHtml.ht**l**m , also
`link : function(element,scope,attrs){`
won't work correctly, since teh order of parameters matters, it should be:
`link : function(scope,element,attrs){`
instead.

Comment: no i am not passing array from the both the instances. Array is generated in the directive(function getdata).

Comment: Then why are you passing it in the isolated scope? That sorta defeats the whole purpose.

Comment: if I remove it from the isolated scope then also it is not working

Comment: is there any way in which we can reload the same templateURL we have already given in the directive

Comment: @ShardulPendse, what you're asking doesnt make sense, when you define a directive in an angular app you can use it in 1000000 different views, I think you're doing something fundamentally wrong. You should post a plunk.